# How to use model passed to Rotativa ViewAsPdf

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rotativa

```
public ActionResult BuildReportView(string temp)
{
    return View(data);
}

public ActionResult Print(string temp)
{
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TransDetRep>(temp);
    var data = GetReportData(obj);
    return new ViewAsPdf("BuildReportView",data);
}
```

Here I'm passing a model called data to ViewAsPdf as I want to return above view as pdf and use the model in that action. I tried using session and temp data but nothing works, I don't understand what's wrong with it.

Comment: Your `BuildReportView.cshtml` has to be a [strongly typed view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0#strongly-typed-data-viewmodel). The link is for .Net Core, but the functionality is the same for earlier versions.

Comment: plz explain what you are trying to say how i can use data i passsed in print action in buildreportview.

Comment: Hi, @Umer. It seems that you are receiving an string called "temp" as parameter in BuildReportView action, and then you pass a variable called "data", which does not exist in the action context. May this be the problem of not receiving the data you want to send? However, it should be useful if you post the view code as well.